# Print order in Magento 1.7 not using theme CSS

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've successfully setup my theme and using it for the rest of my site on Magento 1.7, however the print order screen (`http://<my-domain>/index.php/sales/order/print/order_id`) seems to be ignoring `local.css` and using all of the styles from `styles.css`.

For example `button.button span` from `styles.css` is being used for the **Close** button when I have this in `local.css` and the rest of the site uses this. I've even tried to set a more specific selector but this gets ignored.

Is there something simple I'm missing on this screen as I haven't had this problem anywhere else.

**Edit: Workaround solution:** I viewed the source HTML of the page and can definitely see that `local.css` is **not** loaded anywhere in the page. On other pages I can see it being pulled in. Seems like a bug in Magento 1.7.0.2, so I copied `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/print.phtml` to my template path(`/app/design/frontend/default/<my-theme>/template/page/print.phtml`) and fixed.

It seems this block isn't doing what it's meant to do and does in other pages

```
<head>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
```

So in my copy of the file in my template directory I added the line below just before `</head>` which worked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/local.css') ?>" media="all" />
```

I logged a defect here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=15841